# Wait for functions within a promise to finish

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-promise

I have the following function in an Angular.js controller:

```
vm.some_action = function() {
    var promise = IDService.getUserInfo().then(function(user) {
        vm.user.name = user.name;
        vm.box.color = 'red';
        vm.save()
    }, function(errorResponse) {
        Toast.error("Failed:", errorResponse);
    })

    $q.resolve(promise).then(function() {
        $location.path('/home');
    })
}
```

It should wait for all function calls within the promise to finish and only then redirect to `/home`. However, it seems to execute all three (two assignments and a call to `save()`) and redirect right away. What's the magic way to tell it to wait for the `save()` function to finish as well?

Comment: is ` vm.save()` async? does it return a promise?

Comment: Yes, it's async (stupid Q: aren't all functions in JS async?) and it doesn't return anything.

Comment: There are no stupid questions :) Not all JS functions are async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain your promises like below:

```js
vm.some_action = function() {
    IDService.getUserInfo().then(function(user) {
        vm.user.name = user.name;
        vm.box.color = 'red';
        return vm.save()
    }).then(function() {
        $location.path('/home');
    }, function(errorResponse) {
        Toast.error("Failed:", errorResponse);
    });
}
```

Comment: Does the `vm.save()` function have to return something for this to work?

Comment: Figured it out, yes, the saving function needs to return some success/fail result. Thanks for your answer, worked great!